# htaccess not redirecting to custom 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Everything on my page works except that non existing page is recognised as parameter and that displays page with header and footer.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error
ErrorDocument 403 /error
ErrorDocument 500 /error

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?v=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)-(.*)$ index.php?v=$1&page=$2&folder=$3 [L,QSA]
```

When I try to open mydomain.com/non-existing-page than "non-existing-page" is recognised as parameter $v and page mydomain.com/index.php$v=non-existing-page is opened with only header footer and no content.

Comment: that make sense but most of my links use just one parameter `$v` so my links looks like that `mydomain.com/contact`

Comment: Ok. I should have construct my question differently.  If I remove first `RewritRule` than all single parameters pages (eg.: `mydomain.com/contact`) will not open. Only some pages using more than one parameters. How to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You can change `.*` with `[^/-]+` to allow only single parameter (non-slash+non-hyphen) to be handled by `index.php`.

You can use these rules:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error
ErrorDocument 403 /error
ErrorDocument 500 /error

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+)/?$ index.php?v=$1&page=$2&folder=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Exactly same thing is happening. When I try to open `mydomain.com/non-existing-page` than "non-existing-page" is recognised as parameter `$v` and page `mydomain.com/index.php$v=non-existing-page` is opened with only header footer and no content.

Comment: same thing.  But I see now where the problem is. Anything passed after `mydomain.com/` is treated as $v parameter.  In my content page I have this `if($v=='contact') {include('page/contact.php');}`

Comment: Yes, that's true and that's what I was trying to explain in comments. Your other rule (that I've modified) is handling paths with 2 hyphens.  If your URI is `/foo-bar` with one hyphen then it will goto 404?

Comment: I think solution could be to add 2 hypens at he end to every link `mydomain.com/contact--`  so without hypens would show my custom 404 error page. Can you modify your script?

Comment: Sorry didn't get. How can we insert 2 hyphens after every link as we don't know which one is valid and which one is not.

Comment: I have removed your last `RewiteRule` and I have added 2 hyphens to each link and everything is working fine.  If there is better solution please let me know.

Comment: Your answer in the current state is incorrect. I can't accept it as this will mislead other people.

Comment: I've removed last rule. Anything else is incorrect?